# Loading an SKlearn model from AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scikit-learn

I have saved a sklearn model using the following code:

```
def __init__(self,bucket_name):
    self.bucket_name = bucket_name
    self.s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    self.aws_access_key_id = os.environ['aws_access_key_id']
    self.aws_secret_access_key =  os.environ['aws_secret_access_key']
    self.region ="eu-central-1"
    self.s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=       self.aws_access_key_id,
                             aws_secret_access_key=        self.aws_secret_access_key,
                                  endpoint_url = 'https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com')

    self.s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=       self.aws_access_key_id,
                             aws_secret_access_key=        self.aws_secret_access_key,
                                  endpoint_url = 'https://s3.eu-central-1.wasabisys.com')


def write_as_joblib_to_bucket(self,file,path,file_name):
    full_file_name = path + "/" + file_name

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    joblib.dump(file, fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    response = self.s3.put_object(Body=fp.read(), Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=full_file_name )
                print(response)
```

However, I am not completely sure how to load the model:
I've been trying something like this:

```
def read_joblib_file(self, path, file_name):
    full_file_name = path + "/" + file_name
    obj = self.s3.get_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=full_file_name)
    body = joblib.load(obj['Body'])
```

However, how do i convert the body into the original sklearn format?

Comment: Ended up saving the file as pickle instead and loading it through      model_str  = obj['Body'].read()
        return pickle.loads(model_str)

Comment: I kindly suggest you either post it as an answer so that it can be potentially useful for others (which is [what SO is about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/4685471)), or to delete the post; comments may get deleted at any time without warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Joblib`, `IO` in combination with `boto3`

```py
import boto3 
from joblib import load
from io import BytesIO


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 's3://my-bucket'
key = '/path/to/my/object.joblib'
s3_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
# Write to in-memory buffer and use in place of a file object
# In general, BytesIO is useful when something (e.g. joblib) 
# expects a file object, but we can only provide data directly
bytes_stream = BytesIO(s3_object['Body'].read())
model = load(bytes_stream)
```

This will work, but depending on how large your model is, you may want to explore different options. If you are running into long S3 load times, some things you can try: you can look at using AWS Sagemaker to deploy your model, where you can (in your python script) just invoke an endpoint with your data as a payload and retrieve a result (see [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/84af8989d065)); you can do the same Sagemaker deployment then invoke it in AWS Athena (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/prepare-data-for-model-training-and-invoke-machine-learning-models-with-amazon-athena/)); etc...

Answer (score 0):

By following a similar idea in your write function you can read your sklearn model as in the following:

```
def read_joblib_file(self, key):

    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:

        s3.dowload_fileobj(Fileobj=fp,Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=key)
        fp.seek(0)
        model = joblib.load(fp)

    return model
```